# KiCad mouse cursor freezing in schematic

Tags: kicad

I've begun to make a transition from EAGLE to KiCad (wasn't particularly familiar with EAGLE either).

I've installed KiCad  4.05 just because it seems there were more tutorials and info available out there than KiCad 5.0 yet.

I've encountered an annoying issue of my cursor freezing quite often in schematic.  I've googled around a bit to resolve this issue. I've tried different DPI settings, to no avail.

I have a workaround where I would just click on my google chrome icon below and then go back to the schematic. I would like to have a permanent solution though if there is one.

Comment: Do you have a "Gaming mouse" with a center button? Or other buttons? A plain USB mouse should always work. A Bluetooth mouse can have connection/DPI issues. It does seem like a program based problem. If it freezes then Windows Desktop/OS is hanging up.

Answer (score 1):

It might help others to help you if you would state your operating system.

If you want to stay at kicad 4 you should at least look into updating to 4.0.7
And you might want to setup your system to use the backported version 5 libs to make transferring your projects over to kicad 5 easier once you want to switch.